# pdfplumber extract table data works when the table has borders, doesn't work when the table has no borders

Tags: python, pdfplumber

Using reportlab I made 2 1 page pdfs with 1 table:

The data in the table is this:

```
data1 = [['00', '', '02', '', '04'],  
['', '11', '', '13', ''],  
['20', '', '22', '23', '24'],  
['30', '31', '32', '', '34']]
```

The point is, to get the rows including the empty cells. If the table has borders, no problem.

But if the table has no borders, I don't get any results for table from the code below.

Any ideas why?

Like I said, the pdfs are identical except for pdf1 does not have borders, pdf2 has borders.

```
with pdfplumber.open(path2pdf + savename1) as pdf1:
    # Get the first page of the object
    page = pdf1.pages[0]
    # Get the text data of the page
    text = page.extract_text()
    # Get all the tabular data of this page
    tables = page.extract_tables()
    # Traversing table
    for t_index in range(len(tables)):
        table = tables[t_index]
        # Traversing each row of data
        for data in table:
            print(data)
```

Change pdf1 for pdf2 and I get the required result.

EDIT: I tried with this, but get an error. Not sure how I should format it:

> > > > pdf_table = page.extract_tables(vertical_strategy='text', horizontal_strategy='text') Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > > > "/usr/lib/python3.8/idlelib/run.py", line 559, in runcode
> > > > exec(code, self.locals)   File "<pyshell#70>", line 1, in  TypeError: extract_tables() got an unexpected keyword argument
> > > > 'vertical_strategy'

Comment: Can you use a service like https://transfer.sh/ to post the two PDFs?

Comment: Do you get anything in the `text` variable ?

Comment: Yes, the text shows the values of the cells with content, no problem. Not sure how to use transfer .sh, but the pdfs are very simple, 1.6 KB. They both only contain a numbers or nothing, 4 rows, 5 columns.

Comment: Anyone with this problem look here: https://pypi.org/project/pdfplumber/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [pdfplumber documentation](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#extracting-tables), when calling the `page.extract_tables()` function, you have some table extraction settings that you may want to implement.

By default, the strategy is to use the **pages vertical or horizontal lines** as cell separators, however, you can specify an alternative **extraction strategy**.

The method can be customised by the following settings:

```
{
    "vertical_strategy": "lines", 
    "horizontal_strategy": "lines",
    "explicit_vertical_lines": [],
    "explicit_horizontal_lines": [],
    "snap_tolerance": 3,
    "snap_x_tolerance": 3,
    "snap_y_tolerance": 3,
    "join_tolerance": 3,
    "join_x_tolerance": 3,
    "join_y_tolerance": 3,
    "edge_min_length": 3,
    "min_words_vertical": 3,
    "min_words_horizontal": 1,
    "keep_blank_chars": False,
    "text_tolerance": 3,
    "text_x_tolerance": 3,
    "text_y_tolerance": 3,
    "intersection_tolerance": 3,
    "intersection_x_tolerance": 3,
    "intersection_y_tolerance": 3,
}
```

The one that you may need to consider is the vertical and horizontal strategy settings.

- **vertical strategy** options: "lines", "lines_strict", **"text"**, or "explicit".
- **horizontal strategy** options: "lines", "lines_strict", **"text"**, or "explicit".
- **min_words_vertical** - When using `"vertical_strategy": "text"`, at least `min_words_vertical` words must share the same alignment.
- **min_words_horizontal** - When using `"horizontal_strategy": "text"`, at least `min_words_horizontal` words must share the same alignment.

#### text:

For `vertical_strategy`: Deduce the (imaginary) lines that connect the left, right, or center of words on the page, and use those lines as the borders of potential table-cells. For `horizontal_strategy`, the same but using the tops of words.

#### Use:

`.extract_table(table_settings={<put settings you need in here>})`

#### Note:

Often it's helpful to crop a page — `Page.crop(bounding_box)` — before trying to extract the table.

Comment: Thanks! I looked in PyPi and found how to use the tabe_settings={} Works now! A lot of settings to manage there!

Comment: Glad it helped - just use the ones you need.